# Probability of N matches as rolls increase

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the formula for the probability of matching any number on an m-sided die, n number of times after r number of rolls.

For the specific example I'm trying to solve, I'm looking at a scenario where it would be a 9 sided die and I would be looking for the probability of the first instance of 9 matches of the same number. So I believe after 9 rolls the probability would be $\frac{1}{9^8}$ as I would need the 8 following rolls to match the first (but I ain't claiming to be good at math so correct me if I messed that up). Unfortunately that's as far as I'm getting with the probability. As soon as roll 10 hits, I'm not sure how to calculate it.

To hopefully further illustrate the ask with an example I'm capable of solving, given a 2 sided die and looking for a match length of 2, there would be a 50% chance of a match on the second roll (or flip) and a 100% chance on the third roll as it would either create a 2 length match with the first roll or the second.

If anything needs clarification, let me know, and apologies if I did something incorrectly. First time posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p=\frac{1}{m}$, then the probability of matching any number $n$ times after $r$ rolls is given by
$$
P_{n,m}(r) = m\times {r\choose n}p^{n}(1-p)^{r-n}
$$
Intuition: pick one particular number, $p^{n}(1-p)^{r-n}$ is the probability of one configuration of $n$ matches after $r$ rolls, there are ${r\choose n}$ of possible rolls and $m$ different numbers. Now we must find out the maximum number of rolls possible until we have our desired amount of matches. That is, we need to solve $\bar{r}$ out of the following equation
$$
\sum_{r=n}^{\bar{r}} {r\choose n}p^{n}(1-p)^{r-n} = \frac{1}{m}
$$
Solving for $\bar{r}$ can be difficult because it will involve using binomial series of negative numbers. Instead, we can proceed by induction:

Suppose $n=2$, then we know for sure that we will have two matches of any number after $m+1$ rolls.

Now suppose $n=3$, then we know for sure that we will have two matches of any number after $2m+1$.

Take arbitrary $n$ and assume the number of rolls is $m(n-1)+1$. Now for $n+1$ we need at most the previous $m(n-1)+1$ rolls plus $m$ more rolls, leaving a total of $mn+1$ rolls. Thus, for a dice with $m$ sides and $n$ matches we will need a total of $\bar{r}=m(n-1)+1$ rolls at most. This expression sounds familiar, because for a given $\bar{r}$ the number of rolls has a negative binomial distribution!